# Color and efficient vector graphics

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, color

I want to use complex monocolor vector graphics but I would like to be able to specify the color inside my latex source. Solutions :

1. Use a `pdf`, but I can't specify the color afterwards. Perhaps a solution with `svg` ?
2. Use `tikz`, but it makes my compilation so slow as it needs to parse the complex paths again each time I use one of those graphics !
3. Use `tikz`+`\savebox`, as my graphics have a lots of complexity, but there are only a few different of them that I use a lots of time.

Here is my question : can I use `\savebox` to save some tikz operations with a custom color that will be specified only when I use `\usebox` ?

My wish would be to have a command `\mygraphics` that takes one argument the color such that `\mygraphics{blue}` and `\mygraphics{red}` typeset my graphic in blue or in red **without** parsing my graphic each time.

Comment: Instead of `savebox` you can define a command with an (optional) argument

Comment: Defining a command with an optional argument is like solution 2 : tikz must parse 100 times the same complex path if I use 100 time the same graphic with different colors...

Comment: How about using the `external` library of TikZ? You can update pictures later by putting `remake next` before them. See section 32 of the TikZ manual for details.

Comment: well if you can show the example of what your complicated graphics is then we can offer more options. If it is only the color you are interested in then you can use masking which is a big advantage of PGF. But I don't see what you mean by complexity. Is it a lot of paths or else? I'm plotting ridiculous amount of bode plots with 2500 points each with pgfplots in my thesis and it takes 3 minutes to compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally found what I need in [programming-in-tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19715/programming-in-tikz/19720#19720). Soft paths allow to compute a path and save it for later, using it with different fill, stroke, ...

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me there is a fourth solution using both an external pdf and tikz. You could compile the tikz using the "standalone" class, an example of such code is given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113668/is-it-possible-to-shift-ticks-position-in-a-graph-to-match-apa-style), then include the obtained pdf in your main document. The compilation would then be fast while keeping full control over the graph.